# Calculating page faults and swap-outs on code

Tags: c, arrays, operating-system, paging, page-fault

I have this exercise to solve that I just can't figure it out on how to solve it.

Question

> Consider that you have three matrices:
>   long A[8][64];
>   long B[8][64];
>   long C[8][64];
>   The **page size** in this system is **1024 Bytes** and a **long** occupies **8 Bytes**. The cache has **3 Page-Frames** for pages. At the beginning, the cache is empty. The system uses LRU algorithm and Modify-Bit.
>   Given the following code:
>   `Program A`
>   `for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
>   for(j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
>    A[i][j] = B[i][j] + C[i][j];
>   }}`
>
> `Program B`
>   `for(j = 0; j < 64; i++) {
>   for(i = 0; i < 8; j++) {
>    A[i][j] = B[i][j] + C[i][j];
>   }}`
>
> A) How many Page-Faults are generated by program A?
>   B) How many Swap-Outs are generated by program A?
>   C) How many Page-Faults are generated by program B?
>   D) How many Swap-Outs are generated by program B?

Thank you all!!

Comment: your question states 'two' arrays, but the actual code uses 'three' arrays,  The posted code snippets are not executable (they do not compile)  How large are the executable(s) in bytes?

Comment: The exercise is solved by applying things you revently learned in your class. Make sure that all the terms and expression are clear to you. If not look them up, preferrably in the text book recommended by the person who gave you the assignment. In this special case you are supposed to act yourself as compiler and CPU and demonstrate your understanding by applying the concepts yourself. Afterwards you will know the numer asked for. Alterniatively, but in my opinion unnlikely, you are asked to compile the code, run it on a platform with the given attributes with a debugger and find out that way.

Comment: This, as all questions which give the strong impression of being a blind homework dump, is too broad to be answered. Please demonstrate your own effort, by turning the code parts into compileable programs and to explain as many of the mentioned technical terms as you can. Then imagine the programs being executed and describe what in your opinion will happen.

Comment: Guys, it's always the homework comments. I don't have classes anymore, so I have no homework. I would appreciate an awser to the question.

Comment: @AlexandreSerra: If "cache" is "translation lookaside buffer" (and not "data cache"), and if the CPU automatically fetches a translation from RAM when there's a TLB miss; and if there's enough RAM (maybe 16 KiB or more); then all of the answers are "zero page faults and zero swap-outs".

Comment: Where in the (*&@# does such a question come from? There is no answer to this question without qualifying it as "at least" I am puzzled why universities make computer programming needlessly complicated with nonsensical questions like this.

Comment: You want an answer to this question, whether homework or not. Did you work towards such an answer, e.g. by following my description? What kind of an answer do you expect which would not be created by applying the same concept? What benefit will an answer give you, if you do not arrive at it by doing it yourself? I.e., if somebody answers e.g."30,  32, 26 and 30", what will it help you?

Comment: @Yunnosch It would benefit me if someone explained to me how it is done. Not give exact awser. O just need an explanation

Comment: Did you read my first comment? I meant it to be exactly what you are now explicitly asking for.

Comment: @Yunnosch have you been on my classes? My teacher didn't provide any material about this matter. I'm sure of that. But anyways since everyone is more concerned about wether it is homework or not, I will be closing this thread.